# Dockerized .Net core "No space left on the device" error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core

On the project, we faced with the issue related to the crash of docker agent "No space left on the device".

On one of the nodes of K8S cluster, we executed the command:

```
# ps -eLf | grep './DotNetApp' | awk '{print $10}' | wc -l
13882
```

It means that all my .Net processes have 13882 threads. On the node, with this leak to a limit of the maximum number of threads.

To check the limit, you can execute:

```
root@ip-172-20-104-47:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
```

"Threads" is the amount, but pid_max is about the pool of the ids. And pods can easily reach this limit and crash docker on the node.

We use CentOS for the K8S worker. We tried Ubuntu and got the same result.

Do you have any ideas, why do we have such a thread leak on Linux nodes under .net core 2.2?

Comment: Can you recreate this issue with a minimal version of your application? Perhaps the result of a `dotnet new console` or dotnet new webapi`?

Comment: We are struggling with this issue during the last half of the year. I think that it is something that is hidden inside the .net core under Linux. I'm going to have more debug information until the end of the week.

Comment: The biggest problem, from the position of someone trying to help, is that I have no idea what your application is doing. For instance, there could (and I do not mean to sound nasty when I say this) be a legitimate thread leak in your code. Do you have similar issues when running the code outside of K8S? Have you attempted to run it on a Mac or Windows server?

Comment: I understand it. I have about 38 services. And 90% of them have a thread leak. What are they doing? Communicate with each other using HTTP calls, generate data to mongo and MSSQL. My question is more about toolset that I can use to understand why do I have such an issue, what part of my code could create problems. I don't believe that people that use .Net core 2.2 with K8S have no similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was quite interesting. We decided to create a health check for Redis. If Redis is not available, we just shot down the pod. However, the implementation of this health check for each /health call, it created the separate connection multiplexer without disposing the old one. So, after the some time the limit of available threads was reached.

So, be careful with implementation of health checks.